# Server side form validation always returns true

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, jform, form, validations

I am trying to validate the input of my form on server side, but I always get true from the validator. What am I doing wrong?

*.../templates/customer_registration.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form name="customer_registration_form" title="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_TITLE" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DESCRIPTION" buttonLabel="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_BUTTON_LABEL">
    <fields name="customer_registration">
        <fieldset name="customer_registration">
            <field name="name" type="text" class="required validate-username" size="80" minLength="4" maxLength="255"
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_MESSAGE" />
            <field name="age" type="integer" class="required" default="6" first="1" last="150" step="1"
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_MESSAGE" />
            <field name="permanent_orderer" type="checkbox" default="1"
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_MESSAGE" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

*.../templates/basic_form_layout.php*

```
<?php
extract($displayData);
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_canteen&controller=main&action=form_test'); ?>"
      method="post" name="<?php echo $form->getAttribute('name'); ?>" class="<?php echo $form->getAttribute('class'); ?>">
    <legend><?php echo JText::_($form->getAttribute('title')); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo JText::_($form->getAttribute('description'));
        foreach (array_keys($form->getFieldsets()) as $fieldset)
            echo $form->renderFieldset($fieldset);
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        <button type="submit"><?php echo JText::_($form->getAttribute('buttonLabel')); ?></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

*.../MainController.php*

```
/**
* @action 
* @allow("public")
*/
public function formTest(iRequest $request, iResponse $response){

    $templateDir = JPATH_COMPONENT . '/Canteen/presentation/templates';
    $form = JForm::getInstance('customer_registration', $templateDir . '/customer_registration.xml');

    $formData = $request->getPostData()->getArray();
    $filtered = $form->filter($formData);

    foreach ($filtered as $fieldset => $fields)
        foreach ($fields as $field => $value)
            $form->setValue($field, $fieldset, $value);

    $result = $form->validate($filtered);

    $content = new HtmlFragment();
    $content->addTemplate($response->getTemplate('basic_form_layout.php'), array('form' => $form));
    $content->addText(var_export($result, true));
    $response->setContent($content);

}
```

I checked the `$filtered` variable; it contains the filtered data without the CSRF token, something like: `{'customer_registration': {name: "", age: "6", permanent_orderer: "1"}}`. Actually no matter what data I give to the `$form->validate($data)`, it always returns true. I'd like to use `JForm` to validate and display error messages. Any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked [the code of the JForm](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/f75801b7fb1d3ca347034399af7a9e250686b0a1/libraries/joomla/form/form.php#L1146).

According to it `class="required validate-username"` does not work, and I should use `required="true"` instead by the fields required.

Everything else is validated by rules. I need to add `validate="ruleType"` to the XML file. The `minLength`, `maxLength` etc. apparently works only by client side, and the server side validation does not follow the HTML5 specs.

I guess I need to define the same rule types on a client side lib too if I want to validate on client side. I checked with HTML5, it worked, but I got no error messages. I thought it is broken, but I guess it does not connect to the HTML5 validation properly. Does not really matter, I don't want to work twice, so I won't have client side validation.

I can read the error messages with `$form->getErrors()`. I thought they are added to the fields, so auto rendering them would show the error messages, but apparently I need to enqueue these messages on the joomla app. It is okay, but could have been better.

note:

I found the related part in the [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field), probably I read too superficial. I did not sleep. :S

I ended up with the following code:

*.../templates/customer_registration.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form name="customer_registration_form" title="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_TITLE" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DESCRIPTION" buttonLabel="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_BUTTON_LABEL">
    <fields name="customer_registration">
        <fieldset name="customer_registration">
            <field name="name" type="text" required="true" size="80"
                validate="text" minLength="4" maxLength="80" pattern="\p{L}+(?:\p{Zs}\p{L}+)+" 
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_NAME_MESSAGE" />
            <field name="age" type="integer" required="true" default="6" first="1" last="150" step="1"
                validate="integer" min="1" max="150"
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_AGE_MESSAGE" />
            <field name="permanent_orderer" type="checkbox" default="1"
                label="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_LABEL" description="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_DESCRIPTION" message="COM_CANTEEN_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_PERMANENT_ORDERER_MESSAGE" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

*.../templates/rules/text.php*

```
<?php

use \SimpleXMLElement;
use \JForm;
use \JRegistry;
use \JFormRule;

class JFormRuleText extends JFormRule {

    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        if (!isset($value))
            $value = '';
        if (!is_string($value))
            return false;

        $length = mb_strlen($value, mb_detect_encoding($value));

        if (isset($element['minLength'])) {
            $minLength = (int) $element['minLength'];
            if ($minLength > $length)
                return false;
        }

        if (isset($element['maxLength'])) {
            $maxLength = (int) $element['maxLength'];
            if ($maxLength < $length)
                return false;
        }

        if (isset($element['pattern'])) {
            $pattern = '/'.$element['pattern'].'/usD';
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $value))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

*.../templates/rules/integer.php*

```
<?php

use \SimpleXMLElement;
use \JForm;
use \JRegistry;
use \JFormRule;

class JFormRuleInteger extends JFormRule {

    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        $intValue = (int) $value;
        if ((string) $intValue !== $value || (float) $intValue !== (float) $value)
            return false;

        if (isset($element['min'])) {
            $min = (int) $element['min'];
            if ($min > $intValue)
                return false;
        }
        if (isset($element['max'])) {
            $max = (int) $element['max'];
            if ($max < $intValue)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

*.../MainController.php*

```
/**
* @action 
* @allow("public")
*/
public function formTest(iRequest $request, iResponse $response){
    $form = $response->getForm('customer_registration.xml', $request->getAddress(), $request->getQuery());
    if ($request->isPost()){
        $form->fill($request->getPostData());
        $isValid = true;
        if (!$request->hasValidToken()) {
            $response->reportError(new Exception('Invalid token.'));
            $isValid = false;
        }
        if (!$form->validate()) {
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error)
                $response->reportError($error);
            $isValid = false;
        }
        if ($isValid) {
            $response->reportSuccess('Customer created.');
            $form->reset();
        }
    }

    $content = new HtmlFragment();
    $content->addForm($form, $response->getTemplate('basic_form_layout.php'));
    $response->setContent($content);
}
```

Ofc. this is still just a dummy proof of concept code to demonstrate that the validation works.

It is possible to override the default error messages too if somebody wants to:

```
// required: JText::sprintf('JLIB_FORM_VALIDATE_FIELD_REQUIRED', $name|label);
// rule: $message | JText::sprintf('JLIB_FORM_VALIDATE_FIELD_INVALID', $label)
```

And by returning an `Exception` instance instead of `false` it is possible to send different error messages from the same rule. So it is not mandatory to use the message given in the XML. For me it was enough.